# Sentence starting with Maybe as question

Tags: questions

Is it correct to use a sentence starting with Maybe as a question, eq.

> Maybe I'll come sometime on Sunday?
>
> Maybe I can help you?

I suspect it is acceptable form for spoken informal context but not sure.

Comment: "Maybe" isn't the *problem*, it's the question mark that marks the statement that's not a *real question* (at least not in its form) as a question. This might come off as informal.

Comment: I think it works better when the subject is not *I*. Consider your sentence without *maybe*: *I'll come sometime on Sunday?* -- Unless the context is right, it'll sound strange because you turn your intention into a question. Adding *maybe* will make it sound even stranger. On the other hand, a sentence such as (asking your friend to confirm your idea) *Maybe he was right?*, which is cast as a question, is fine.

Comment: @DamkerngT. The context here is that someone is making suggestion that he wants to pay a visit to someone he is talking to. I also added another example - "Maybe I can help you?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not it's "grammatically correct", at least here in the US, people say this kind of thing all the time.  Something like:

> Maybe I'll come by next Saturday?

is *definitely* a question, one that is asking for permission or approval.  Asking:

> Maybe I can help you?

is the same as asking "Can I help you?" but with more uncertainty whether you *want* or *need* my help.

That being said, you shouldn't confuse this with the "rhetorical question" structure that is a *statement*:

> Maybe you should have gone to the bathroom before we left the house?

This is not a question, but a statement saying "It would have been a good idea if you had ..."  Similarly:

> Don't you think it would have been good to go to the bathroom before leaving the house?

Prefacing a question with "maybe" is informal, and is more common in certain cultures and dialects than others, so I would be careful using it -- especially since the regular question structure is always acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Since you used "maybe" in your statement, it no longer is a question.
***Maybe*** can't come in an interrogative question, and you shall never see it, you will only see it as an answer, not as a question:

> Will you come back next week? - Maybe I will come back next week.

***Maybe*** means a possibility, and there are others ways to turn your statement into a possibility question: *Will I be back anytime on Sunday?*
It's the closest I got in turning your statement into a possibility question.